# SSIS Data Import Primary key seeds and Foreign key management

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, ssis

I am currently shifting partial data from our local production database to an amazon RDS instance.i do not need all the data but just some rows and all its dependencies (other tables). I have made a script but found out the latency makes the shift of the data extremely slow so therefore i have turned to SSIS.

Now i am in need of help as to how do i manage the existing foreign keys to update to the new primary key seeds. i have added oid (Original ID) columns on the parent tables in the destination database and would just join the foreign keys on the OID and update to the id column.

How would i do this in SSIS?

Comment: I would avoid changing your PKs at all costs in the first place, but if it's unavoidable, you would usually do this with a Lookup component.

Comment: Hi Tab ,Lookup worked well! thanks so much!